# What library do you use for matrix calculations on CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda, scientific-computing

What  library do you use for matrix calculations on CUDA? Or are there any? It seems as if everybody writes this by himself.

For usual processors, I use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). What about GPUs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For dense matrix operations, you could consider [CUBLAS](http://developer.nvidia.com/getcuda) (provided with the CUDA Toolkit), [Magma](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/) and [CULAtools](http://www.culatools.com/).

For sparse matrix operations consider [CUSPARSE](http://developer.nvidia.com/getcuda) (provided with the CUDA Toolkit) and [CUSP](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/).

Answer (score 7):

What are the problems you're dealing with?
For sparse matrix calculations [CUSP](http://code.google.com/p/cusp-library/) is quite a good library.
For dense problems [Magma](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/index.html) might be a better fit.